# What is the fastest way to modify my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

The dataframe has 122,145 rows.
Following is snippet of data :

```
country_name,subdivision_1_name,subdivision_2_name,city_name
Spain,Madrid,Madrid,Sevilla La Nueva
Spain,Principality of Asturias,Asturias,Sevares
Spain,Catalonia,Barcelona,Seva
Spain,Cantabria,Cantabria,Setien
Spain,Basque Country,Biscay,Sestao
Spain,Navarre,Navarre,Sesma
Spain,Catalonia,Barcelona,Barcelona
```

I want to substitute city_name with subdivision_2_name whenever both the following conditions are satisfied:

1. subdivision_2_name and city_name have same country_name and same
   subdivision_1_name , and
2. subdivision_2_name is present in city_name.

ex: For city_name "Seva" the subdivison_2_name "Barcelona" is present as a city_name as well in the dataframe with the same country_name "Spain" and same subdivision_1_name "Catalonia" , so I will replace "Seva" with "Barcelona".

I am able to create a proper apply func. I have prepared a loop:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.subdivision_2_name[i] in set(df.city_name[(df.country_name == df.country_name[i]) & (df.subdivision_1_name == df.subdivision_1_name[i])]):
        df.city_name[i] = df.subdivision_2_name[i]
```

Edit : This loop took 1637 seconds(~28 min) to run

Suggest me a better method.

Comment: Sorry, I run your code with sample data and not replace. I try understand `For city_name "Seva" the subdivison_2_name "Barcelona" is present as a city_name as well in the dataframe with the same country_name "Spain" and same subdivision_1_name "Catalonia" , so I will replace "Seva" with "Barcelona".` but failed.

Comment: Maybe problem is in sample data is no `subdivision_2_name is present in city_name`

Comment: so `Seva` cannot be replaced. Is possible change data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add expected output, it means what values are replaced?

Comment: The snippet example was just to give the context about the problem. In the complete data under the subsets of subdivision_1_name "Catalonia" and subdivision_2_name "Barcelona", there is multiple values in the city_name. One is "Barcelona" in city_name. In this case "Seva" will be changed to "Barcelona".
I will add that to the snippet to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: it is really hard answer without [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jezrael , updated the snippet with proper sample data that follows the condition. Thanks for suggesting useful edits to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
def f(x):
    if x['subdivision_2_name'].isin(x['city_name']).any():
        x['city_name'] = x['subdivision_2_name']
    return (x)

df1 = df.groupby(['country_name','subdivision_1_name','subdivision_2_name']).apply(f)
print (df1)
  country_name        subdivision_1_name subdivision_2_name         city_name
0        Spain                    Madrid             Madrid  Sevilla La Nueva
1        Spain  Principality of Asturias           Asturias           Sevares
2        Spain                 Catalonia          Barcelona         Barcelona
3        Spain                 Cantabria          Cantabria            Setien
4        Spain            Basque Country             Biscay            Sestao
5        Spain                   Navarre            Navarre             Sesma
6        Spain                 Catalonia          Barcelona         Barcelona
```